# SlideTabProduct prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I would like to random the products that appear in producttabslider module.

```
public function hookblockPosition3($params) {
        $nb = Configuration::get($this->name . '_p_limit');
        $newProducts = Product::getNewProducts((int) Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5));
        $specialProducts = Product::getPricesDrop((int) Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5),false,'date_add', 'DESC');
        shuffle($specialProducts);
        ProductSale::fillProductSales();
        $bestseller =  $this->getBestSales ((int) Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5), null,  null);
        shuffle($bestseller);
        $category = new Category(Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory(), (int) Context::getContext()->language->id);
        shuffle($category);
        $featureProduct = $category->getProducts((int) Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5),'date_add', 'DESC');
```

I tried to enter shuffle(); but it makes random only the latest products added, and not the entire catalog.
Who helps me?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$nb = Configuration::get($this->name . '_p_limit');
$newProducts = Product::getNewProducts((int) Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5),false,'rand');
$specialProducts = Product::getPricesDrop((int) Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5),false,'date_add', 'DESC');
ProductSale::fillProductSales();
$bestseller =  $this->getBestSales ((int) Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5), 'rand',  null);
$category = new Category(Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory(), (int) Context::getContext()->language->id);
$featureProduct = $category->getProducts((int) Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5),'date_add', 'DESC',false,true,true);
```

Now the controller:
create override classes/ProductSale.php and after

```
    if ($order_by == 'date_add' || $order_by == 'date_upd') {
        $order_table = 'product_shop';
    }

    if (is_null($order_way) || $order_by == 'sales') {
        $order_way = 'DESC';
    }
```

add:

```
if ($order_by == 'rand'){
    $order_by = 'RAND()';
    $order_way = '';
}
```

create override classes/Product.php and modify this

```
    if ($order_by == 'id_product' || $order_by == 'price' || $order_by == 'date_add' || $order_by == 'date_upd') {
        $order_by_prefix = 'product_shop';
    } elseif ($order_by == 'name') {
        $order_by_prefix = 'pl';
    }
    if (!Validate::isOrderBy($order_by) || !Validate::isOrderWay($order_way)) {
        die(Tools::displayError());
    }
```

in:

```
if ($order_by == 'id_product' || $order_by == 'price' || $order_by == 'date_add' || $order_by == 'date_upd') {
        $order_by_prefix = 'product_shop';
    } elseif ($order_by == 'name') {
        $order_by_prefix = 'pl';
    }
    if ((!Validate::isOrderBy($order_by) || !Validate::isOrderWay($order_way)) && $order_by != 'rand') {
        die(Tools::displayError());
    }elseif ($order_by == 'rand') {
        $order_by = 'RAND()';
        $order_way = '';            
    }
```

Comment: I did what you told me, but it does not work. You can view it in a tab "In saldo" and "I più venduti" "In saldo" -> specialProducts "I più venduti" -> bestseller

http://www.sexyshopwebstore.it/new_site/